# Cannot POST with Postman - Error 405 / Error 500 in response - Laravel json API

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a JSON API with Laravel. and I'm trying to test it with POSTMAN before continuing to build a front end for it.
My API is a  News Dashboard backend that does the CRUD functions.

Here are the routes:

```
Route::get('/news', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@index')->name('news.index');
Route::get('/news/{newsItem}', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@show')->name('news.show');
Route::post('/news', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@store')->name('news.store');
Route::patch('/news/{newsItem}', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@update')->name('news.update');
Route::delete('/news/{newsItem}', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@destroy')->name('news.destroy');
```

The /news showing me and empty array [] , because the DB is empty for now. the postman GET is returning 200 OK too.  I tried to post JSON payload using postman :

```
{
  "title": "Example News Item",
  "content": "This is the content of the news item.",
  "category_id": 1,
  "tags": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

At first I get the error `419 unknown status` ; then I moved my routes from web.php to api.php and the index is /api/news instead of /news.

So I'm testing `/api/news`

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/`  returns `200 OK`
but

`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/` returns `405 Method Not Allowed`

why is this? is there something wrong with my code?

Here is the store() method in the newscontroller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'nullable|exists:categories,id',
            'tags' => 'array',
            'tags.*' => 'exists:tags,id'
        ]);
    
        $newsItem = new NewsItem;
        $newsItem->title = $request->title;
        $newsItem->body = $request->body;
        $newsItem->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $newsItem->url = $request->url;
        $newsItem->save();
    
        $newsItem->tags()->attach($request->tags);
    
        return response()->json($newsItem, 201);
    }
```

If I remove the validation I get the error 500 instead with the body:
`` 500Internal Server Error  Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;title&#039; cannot be null (SQL: insert into `news_items` (`title`, `body`, `category_id`, `url`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 2022-12-31 14:52:26, 2022-12-31 14:52:26)) ``

But the thing is that my payload contains the required fields.

I don't know where the problem is originating, somehow the payload is not going to the database.

- I can post new items directly from database and the App\Model is working fine too because I can post with laravel tinker and save it. But I cannot post using the postman.

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/ returns 405 Method Not Allowed <<<=== focus on that one. If you still have it, open your api.php and find the route for /news, copy/paste it here

Comment: 500Internal Server Error  Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;title&#039; cannot be null  <<<<=== if you still have it, post the result of `dd($request->all());` in your original question

Comment: Here is the route: ```Route::post('/news', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController@store')->name('news.store');```

Comment: Yes I'm still having the error. how should I do this dd($request->all()) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was wrong with the code. The root cause lies in Postman.
You need to set Accept: application/json header in Postman.
(The hint was that the application Handler was returning HTML instead of JSON in Postman)

[image: You should go to the header section and set : Content-Type: application/json]